# Opencv floodFill: How do I transform from image to mask coordinates?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, flood-fill

I use `floodFill` on my android application. Opencv floodfill function changes mask input image.

```
public static int floodFill(Mat image,
        Mat mask,
        Point seedPoint,
        Scalar newVal,
        Rect rect,
        Scalar loDiff,
        Scalar upDiff,
        int flags)
```

I read this function usage from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/). The documentation says that

> Operation mask that should be a single-channel 8-bit image, 2 pixels wider and 2 pixels taller than image.

and

> Note: Since the mask is larger than the filled image, a pixel (x, y) in image corresponds to the pixel (x+1, y+1) in the mask.

But I think that, if I want to access (x,y), I use (x+2,y+2). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trust the documentation! (Well, most of the time... :-)

The Mask is 2 pixel wider and taller than the input image, but one stripe of pixels is used on top/left of the image, and the other on bottom/right of the image.

As you correctly say, during floodfill, all inputImage coordinates are translated to mask coordinates by summing (1,1).

For example, when reaching any point at the left edge of the image located at coordinates `x = 0, y = y0`, the algorithm will check in the mask the 8 points centered around the coordinates `x = 1, y = y0 + 1`, which includes the point `x = 0, y = y0 + 1` (immediately on the left). If you didn't sum 1, you would exit from the image boundaries.

When reaching the right edge of the image located at coordinates `x = inputImage.cols -1, y = y0`, the algorithm will check in the mask the 8 points centered around the coordinates `x = inputImage.cols, y = y0 + 1`, which includes the point `x = inputImage.cols + 1, y = y0 + 1` (immediately on the right). If your mask was not 2 pixels wider than the original image, you would exit from the image boundaries.

That is why you need a mask image 2 pixels wider than the input image, while summing (1,1) to transform from image to mask coordinates.

All these considerations are valid of course for the `y` coordinate, to explain why the mask has to be 2 pixels higher than the input image.

Note: considerations are the same if you are using a 4 neighborhood instead of an 8 neighborhood.